# Creating new columns based on date value and unique column value?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, pivot-table, grouping

I have a dataframe that looks like this (far more rows).

```
                End Period   EBITDA      Revenue
ID          
XRX US Equity   2013-12-31  2.747000    2.000600
XRX US Equity   2014-12-31  1.914000    1.267900
XYL US Equity   2013-12-31  5.130000    3.837000
XYL US Equity   2014-12-31  6.050000    3.916000
```

How would I go about getting something like this?

```
                 EBITDA      EBITDA      Revenue     Revenue
ID               2013-12-31  2014-12-31  2013-12-31  2014-12-31
XRX US Equity    2.747000    1.914000    2.000600    1.267900
XYL US Equity    5.130000    6.050000    3.837000    3.916000
```

Comment: `df.set_index(['End Period'], append=True).unstack('End Period')`?

Comment: @QuangHoang I don't think that will work because I don't have unique values in End Period

Comment: as long as you don't have duplicate `('ID', 'End Period')` pairs. If you do, your data doesn't make much sense IMHO.

Comment: @QuangHoang I don't have duplicate ('ID', 'End Period') - even on the exact dataset i exampled above, I get  "Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape"

Comment: Runs fine on my end, are you sure you have `append=True`?

Comment: [https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use pivot?

```
df = pd.reset_index().pivot(df,index='ID', columns=['End Period'])
```

Comment: `'ID'` is the index, so maybe `reset_index` before pivot?